# MS Access logging users entrance and exit times across network

Tags: variables, ms-access, scope

Hey guys I need some help. I was tasked with a business intelligence project where the initial step is logging users’ entrance and exit dates and times. So I have three modules:
modCaptureIns and modCaptureOuts; Also, I have modCaptureIns' function RecordIns() running on the AutoExec macro and modCaptureOuts running on when a hidden form named frmCaptureOuts is closed (upon user closing database).

Here is the problem: When a single user opens and closes the database entrance and exit times are logged in tblInsNOuts. As soon as you have more than one user, the second user is changing the SessId variable to a different number, and then the exit times are not recorded. Please give me a hand. Any help will be much appreciated.

CF

```
`Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public SessID As Integer

Public Function RecordIns()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

SessID = DFirst("[MaxOfSessionID]", "[qryMaxOfSessionID]") + 1

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblInsNOuts")

rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("SessionID") = SessID
rs.Fields("WinID") = GetUser()
rs.Fields("EntryStamp") = Now()
rs.Update

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

ExitSub:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub

End Function


Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ExitStamp()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim fldEnumerator As Object
Dim fldColumns As Object

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblInsNOuts")
Set fldColumns = rs.Fields

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

While Not rs.EOF
    For Each fldEnumerator In rs.Fields
        If fldEnumerator.Name = "SessionID" Then
            If fldEnumerator.Value = SessID Then
                rs.Edit
                rs.Fields("ExitStamp") = Now()
                rs.Update
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

ExitSub:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub

End Function

Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Close()
    Call ExitStamp
End Sub

`
```

Answer (score 1):

I went a step further with this. I was able to open another Windows image and therefore a second snapshot of the DB. When I opened both snapshots at the same time it logs the entry times for both, but when close the first one it drops the value of SessID. I realized the snapshot which remains open could no longer access the value of SessID because it's now null. Still need some help guys